# Can we have spaces for property values in property file?

Tags: spring

I want to have a property file configured for msgs shown to end user for example:-

```
GREETINGS=Hello how are you
```

Can it be possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes possible did you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its completely possible
if you are getting any error please post the details of it.